# New sinatra object for every requests but initialize only called once

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I created a very simple web server through the following script:

```
require 'sinatra'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

    def initialize(app = nil)
        super(app)
        puts "******** constructing myapp **********"
    end

    get '/' do
        return "object id: #{object_id}, class #{self.class}"
    end

end

MyApp.run!
```

If I run this little web server and then call `wget -q -O  - http://localhost:4567` for the first time, I see this in my console running my server:

```
******** constructing myapp **********
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2017:16:47:39 EST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31
- -> /
```

and wget prints:

```
object id: 10454240, class MyApp
```

As expected, on the first call, a MyApp object gets created and `initialize` gets called.

Then, if I do a second call to `wget -q -O  - http://localhost:4567`, I see this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2017:16:49:11 EST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31
- -> /
```

And the output of wget prints this:

```
object id: 9387860, class MyApp
```

So, on the second call, I have a different instance of MyApp (because object_id does not have the same value as on the frist call) **but** the `initialize` is not called. How is it possible to have a new object created and bypassing the call to `initialize`?

Comment: Maybe it's not creating a new instance each time like you think it is.

Comment: Without knowing Sinatra, but perhaps the App instance is cloned or duped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new class is created for every request.The instance is not reated with `Sinatra::Application.new` but with `Sinatra::Application.prototype.dup` that's why `initialize` is not called every times. See
[document link](https://sinatrarb.com/intro#requestinstance-scope)
for the code.

Comment: Just to be more precise for ruby beginners like me: for every incoming request, a new instance is created by calling `dup`. It is possible to implement `initialize_dup` and add a print in there to see that `dup` was called.